# How to whitelist azure API management in storage account's firewall?

Tags: azure, networking, firewall, azure-table-storage, azure-api-management

I am using an Azure API management service to serve as a small API accessing a table storage in my storage account. I am using the table storage REST API (eg: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities)

I had no problems accessing the tablestorage using sharedkey-lite authorization, running a little script in policies, but due to business needs I needed to restrict access to the storage account.

Because of monetary considerations I cannot put the apim inside the vnet (nor external or internal) so I need to find another way to access the storage account.

I have tried adding the apim public ip to the firewall exceptions, but that still returned 403 forbidden.

I have added a managed identity allowing read access to the entire storage account and using the policy expression:

`<authentication-managed-identity resource="https://storage.azure.com/"/>`

But after digging more into the docs it seems that table storage is not supported by MSI only blob and queue (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities#azure-storage-blobs-and-queues)

Does anyone has an idea how to access the table storage REST API? I cannot wrap my head around why IP whitelisting does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This 403 forbidden error only have two ways to solve:

1, put the api in a vnet and let vnet access.

2, let the outbound ip of the service to access. You need to get the outbound ip.

Comment: 1. This is not an option for us
2. We would have like to include the outbound ip of the APIM in the network rules, but according to microsoft docs APIM is a special horse:
Some Microsoft services operate from networks that can't be included in your network rules. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#trusted-microsoft-services)

According to this I assume I cannot simply whitelist the APIM manager's public IP

Comment: @GergKllai1 There should be only the two methods I mentioned to solve the 403forbidden problem. . .